Tree with std::unique_ptr. Reference cannot be bound to dereferenced null pointer in well-defined C++ code
I am trying to write a tree data structure with unique_ptr but I ma getting following warning while printing the Tree:
struct Node {
    int data_{0};
    std::unique_ptr<Node> left_{nullptr};
    std::unique_ptr<Node> right_{nullptr};
};

void print(Node &root) {
    if (&root == nullptr) return;
    print(*root.left_);
    std::cout << root.data_ << " ";
    print(*root.right_);
}

I get following warning from compiler:
Reference cannot be bound to dereferenced null pointer in well-defined C++ code; comparison may be assumed to always evaluate to false.
In print(...) function.
How to fix this warning?
I want solve this using unique_ptr.

if (&root == nullptr) return; This condition cannot be true in a conforming program free of undefined behavior. If it's true, then at some earlier point the program essentially did Node& root = *nullptr; whereupon it exhibited undefined behavior by way of dereferencing a null pointer.

print(*root.left_); Ah, right there - deferenceing the null pointer.

You need to test whether root.right_ and/or root.left_ are null before applying the * operator to them.

Contrary to a common misconception ,  bool conversion and negation are handy for such situations: if(not root) return;. But the overall design of this code needs a lot of revision; thus, I can not leave a full-fledged answer due to volume of information.

You test if the address of root is equal to nullptr. The address of a reference variable can not be nullptr.
void print(Node &root) {
    if (&root == nullptr) return; // will never be true

What you probably want is to check if the unique_ptrs are not empty before dereferencing them:
void print(const Node& root) {
    if (root.left_) print(*root.left_);   // check added
    std::cout << root.data_ << ' ';
    if (root.right_) print(*root.right_); // check added
}

Alternatively, use pointers:
void print(const Node* root) {
    if(root == nullptr) return;      // now this check makes sense
    print(root->left_.get());
    std::cout << root->data_ << ' ';
    print(root->right_.get());
}

...or pass a reference to the unique_ptr directly:
void print(const std::unique_ptr<Node>& root) {
    if (root == nullptr) return;
    print(root->left_);
    std::cout << root->data_ << ' ';
    print(root->right_);
}


If using raw pointers, ensure your class cleans up after itself. Rule of three/five/zero

@Chris In the alternative, the pointers are still owned by unique_ptrs though, so if that is used, it should be fine.

Specifically, if "ownership" is not involved since you just take a pointer as parameter and don't store it for later use, raw pointers are perfectly fine. It also means you don't commit this particular function to unique_ptr, shared_ptr or whatever other smartpointer might be in play to handle the ownership.
